# statistics question (independent sampling)

Tags: statistics

You would like to know if pass rates are higher amongst individuals who take CFA preparation courses than amongst those who do not. You randomly sample 500 exam takers who took the CFA level I exam in December and obtain the following results Took prep course: number passed: 122 counts: 271 did not take prep course: number passed: 88 counts: 229

(a) What are the null and alternative hypotheses? Clearly define any symbols that you use (e.g., $μ, p$, etc.)

$H_0: p_1-p_2=0$

$H_A: p_1-p_2≠0$

$\hat p_1= \frac{122}{500}=0.244$; $\hat p_2 = \frac{88}{500}=0.176$

$\hat p = \frac{271(0.244)+229(0.176)}{271+229} = 0.212856$

(b) Find and interpret the p-value for the hypothesis test described in part (a)

b) $$z= \frac{0.244-0.176}{\sqrt{0.213\times 0.787\times(1/271+1/271)}} = 1.85$$ 
$P(|z|> 1.85) =0.99322\times2=0.0644$

$0.0644>0.05$ so do not reject $H_0$.

Is that right?

Comment: It's going to be in your best interested to type out the relevant information in this and future post. Images generally don't receive positive feedback. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I've never heard of the significance level of a test (I don't think). Does that mean p value? In which case, yes you would not reject the null hypothesis.

Comment: it's the t value. question 3! thanks! http://i.imgur.com/QdiNml4.jpg

Comment: I think you meant part d., and like I said before, I don't think I've ever heard of "the significance of the $t$-test" before. I usually hear/read about the "$t$-statistic" of "$p$-value". In either case, if it is the t statistic, it is too small, and if it is a p value, it is too large, if I'm not mistaken. So, in either case you do not reject the null hypothesis.

Comment: Possibly, if I recall how to do them.

Comment: thanks! 
When working properly, an espresso machine at Starbucks dispenses 1 ounce shots of espresso on average. There is some variability in the amount dispensed and the standard deviation is 0.1
(a) To determine if the machine is working properly, the manager at Starbucks makes 35 shots of espresso and records the amounts dispensed. Assume that these 35 shots represent a random sample. What is the expected value and standard deviation of the average amount dispensed?

Comment: (b) The manager considers the machine to be working properly if the average amount dispensed is between 0.97 and 1.03 ounces. Assuming that the machine is working properly, what’s the probability that the average amount dispensed is outside of this range?

Comment: (c) The manager checks to see if the machine is working properly many times a year. Since it takes a long time to make 35 shots, he would prefer to only use a sample of 20 espresso shots to check that the machine is working correctly. Under what additional assumption do we know the sampling distribution of the average of 20 espresso shots? Describe two ways that you could check to see if this assumption is reasonable?

Comment: I forgot to mention, you're free to post a new question. You should post these as a new question. We ask that you include your thoughts and work in progress in every post. Formatting tips [here.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: So just try to include your work and thoughts. It is more likely that you receive positive/constructive feedback that way.

Comment: thanks. I'm so confused if I did it right or not. please look at it. Thanks!

Comment: You would like to know if pass rates are higher amongst individuals who take CFA preparation courses than amongst those who do not. You randomly sample 500 exam takers who took the CFA level I exam in December and obtain the following results Took prep course: number passed: 122 counts: 271 did not take prep course: number passed: 88 counts: 229

Comment: (a) What are the null and alternative hypotheses? Clearly define any symbols that you use (e.g., μ, p, etc.
h0: p1-p2=0 ha: p1-p2≠0
p hat 1= 122/500=0.244 p hat 2= 88/500=0.176
p hat = 271(0.244)+229(0.176) / 271+229 = 0.212856
(b) Find and interpret the p-value for the hypothesis test described in part (a)
b) z= 0.244-0.176 / square root 0.213 x0.787 x (1/271+1/271) = 1.85
l z l > 1.85
p=0.99322x2=0.0644
0.0644>0.05 so do not reject ho.
is that right? I'm so confused.

Comment: I formatted your work above. Please check that it is what you meant to write. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Your numbers seem plausible, but I'm not sure. It has been a while for me.

Comment: hi, I did u1-u2>0

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but you are free to edit the work yourself. Take a look at the formatting quick reference [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to become familiar with how to format your own work.